# grep pattern out from lines e.g. grep("Oh|oh", word, value = TRUE)

Tags: regex, r

using regular expression in R, an example of data below:

```
word <-c("Look at this and say: Oh ya," , 
         "Oh thanks!", 
         "what?! Oh my god!",
         "oh, No!", 
         "What's that for?", 
         "Don't you see that? oh you don't care.")
```

So I want to grep the pattern Oh or oh:

```
wordy = grep("Oh|oh", word, , value = TRUE)
wordy
```

look at the result:

```
[1] "Look at this and say: Oh ya,"          
[2] "Oh thanks!"                            
[3] "what?! Oh my god!"                     
[4] "oh, No!"                               
[5] "Don't you see that? oh you don't care."
```

Is there any way I can get the matched pattern but not the whole line?
e.g. I want to remove the words before "Oh|oh" in [1],[3],[5] but still keep the words after "Oh|oh"

Please give me some tips ! Thanks so much !

Comment: As an aside, `"[Oo]h"` is a more economical regex.

Comment: This approach would (the OP's logic) would turn `This is John my friend` into `oh my friend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove words one way would be using `(g)sub`. e.g in this case to remove everything before the matched pattern....

```
sub( "^.*(oh|Oh)(.*$)" , "\\1\\2" , wordy )
#[1] "Oh ya,"             "Oh thanks!"         "Oh my god!"         "oh, No!"           
#[5] "oh you don't care."
```

`^` zero width anchor for beginning of string, `.*` any characters , `(oh|Oh)` a back-referenced group for the desired pattern, and `(.*$)` a second back-referenced group for everything after the matched pattern up to the end of the string ( the `$`).

The replacement `"\\1\\2"` defines what we want to output, i.e. everything matched in the first and second sets of parentheses. Thus removing everything up to the match of `oh|Oh`.

Comment: Thanks! explained so well!

Comment: +1 Slightly more economical: `sub( "^.*?([Oo]h.*$)" , "\\1" , wordy )`. I made the first match non-greedy to get the first instance of `[Oo]h`.

Answer (score 2):

This is really easy to do with `stringr::str_match`:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(word, "[Oo]h.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
substr(wordy, regexec("Oh|oh", wordy), nchar(wordy))
```